# Scrolling inside a Colorbox div

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a Colorbox which opens a hidden div with 2 major divs inside.

```
<div style="display:hidden">
  <div id="legal">
    <div id="tos">Long html here</div>
    <div id="daten">Another Long html here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally there are 2 separate javascript functions that call the same colorbox from flash:

```
function invoke_tos() {
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#legal', top: 300});
}
function invoke_daten() {
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#legal', top: 300});
}
```

what I want is invoke_daten to open the "legal" div but scroll to "daten" section.

Is this possible with colorbox or jquery without using additional plugins? If yes how?

Comment: So what you don't want is `$.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#daten', top: 300});`?

I'd imagine something like `$.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#legal', top: 300}); $.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#daten', top: 300});` should work, but your browser will probably be so fast you won't even notice it went to #legal first.

Comment: I want to show both nested divs but scroll to second. Something like anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing same situation as @alexander-nenkov clarified in his follow-up comment: "want to show both nested divs but scroll to second. Something like anchor."

I believe this is IMPOSSIBLE for inline mode, simply because the traditional anchor notation "#inline_content" has been used by colorbox to trigger inline content, and we can not have "#inline_content#anchor" notation (at the time of writing this post).

Actually colorbox author, Jack Moore, answered similar question here: "You should be using an iframe". https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/colorbox/O3ZrA8fvjaU

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have noticed the wrong syntax, but in the second function you have two () ...